# Tensorflow : FixedLenFeature Number of bytes values != expected

Tags: python, arrays, file-io, tensorflow

I try to load examples from a tfrecords file. I have a reader function like :

```
def read_record(filename_queue):
    reader = tf.TFRecordReader()

    key, record_string  = reader.read(filename_queue)


    features = {
    "feature": tf.FixedLenFeature([], dtype=tf.string),
    }


    ex_dict = tf.parse_single_example(record_string, features)

    ex_feature = tf.decode_raw(ex_dict["feature"], tf.float32)

    return ex_feature
```

I've just followed https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/how_tos/reading_data/fully_connected_reader.py

But then

```
example_features = read_record(filename_queue)
values = sess.run({"features":example_features})
```

stops with the following error :

> InvalidArgumentError: Name: , Key: feature, Index: 0.  Number of bytes values != expected.  Values size: 4096 but output shape: []
>   Caused by op u'ParseSingleExample/ParseExample/ParseExample'

What is wrong (I know I can mention the actual size but I don't want this) ?

Answer (score 6):

Ok, I've found myself. The problem is during writing :

I defined an example with :

```
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                'feature' : tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(
                    value=value))}))
```

but I've should have used rather

```
example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature={
                'feature' : tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(
                    value=[value]))}))
```